# How I can set focus an cell item in a tableview with specified row and column number in QML?

Tags: qt, indexing, model, qml, tableview

I have a tableView with C++ model in my qml.I need to realize a function of findind. I can get every modeldata by:

in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<TableModel>("App.Class", 0, 1, "TableModel");
qmlRegisterType<Variable>("App.Class", 0, 1, "Variable");
qmlRegisterUncreatableMetaObject(MetaTypeNamespace::staticMetaObject, "App.Class", 0, 1, "MetaType", "Access to enums & flags only");
```

in qml:

```
tableModel.data(tableModel.index(rowNum, colNum),Class.TableModel.CellDataRole)
```

That is OK. But I need to flag the item matched, such as focus it, set specified color and so on.

I have no idea to access the item(delegate by component Text).

How to access to a specified item and change its property?

I hope that focus jump to the matched item and highlight it.And then user can edit value of the item.Just like as the find function of EXCEL

Comment: What is TableView ?, In QML there are several items that have the name of TableView: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html , https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html

Comment: It should be https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html，I use it through import these component as below  import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Comment: For what you want to do that? Actually setting focus to a cell do nothing I think. What is your _real target_?

Comment: I want to jump to this item and highlight it and make user can edit value of the item when search matched